# Uncaught TypeError: this.impl.controls.activateTool is not a function

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I am using Autodesk Viewer to view rvt models in browser. It is working fine on desktop browsers but not in mobile browsers. I tried remote debugging and found the error. This is the screenshot of the console showing the error message.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6L7Gf.jpg)

Anyone know why this error is showing on the mobile browsers.

Comment: Copy the text of your error message into your post rather than showing an image.

Comment: Did you remove viewer container div after viewer had initialized?According to the snapshot, this issue might be caused by missing viewer container. But I'm not able to tell the detail, I cannot obtain further information without seeing any codes. Can you provide some codes demonstrating how you initialize your viewer app? If your codes can't be posted here, please email to `forge.help@autodesk.com`